# horizontal bar plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'am trying doing a bar chart from this data frame with ggplot2 to compare data from Uniprot and macki columns.

```
 Famille Uniprot    Macki
 SN_02     26           7
 SN_03     21          22
 SN_04     16           7
 SN_05      4           0
 SN_09     10           0
 SN_10      5           0
 SN_17      6           0
 SN_19     13           4
 SN_20      3           1
 SN_31      2           0
 SN_32      5           3
 SN_33      3           0
 SN_34      1           0
 SN_37      3           0
```

This is my R code:

```
bar <- c(26, 21, 16,4,10,5,6,13,3,2,5,3,1,3,7,22,7,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,3,0,0,0)
lab <- c("SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17","SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37", "SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17", "SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37")
pct <- round(bar/sum(bar)*100)
lab <- paste(lab,"%", sep = "")
lab <- paste(lab, pct)
lab0 <- c("SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17", "SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37", "SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17", "SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37")
nlab <- length(lab)
type <- rep("Uniprot:MACKI", each=nlab/2)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
dd <- data.frame(lab0, type, bar, pct)
dd$lab0 <- reorder(dd$lab0,-dd$bar)
ggplot(dd,aes(x=lab0,y=bar,fill=lab0))+geom_bar(aes(alpha=factor(bar)), stat = "identity",
position=position_dodge(width=1))+scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.5,1.0))+
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(pct,"%"),group=interaction(lab0,type)),hjust=-0.5, position=position_dodge(width=1))
+ coord_flip()+expand_limits(y=20)+labs(x="",y="total")
```

And this is the plot i've got [this horizontal bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APVna.png)

Can you help me debug my code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

adding object to ggplot2 is through `+`, which has to be in the same line. Take a look at one line before last - you have to put `+` there. After modification code works

```
bar <- c(26, 21, 16,4,10,5,6,13,3,2,5,3,1,3,7,22,7,0,0,0,0,4,1,0,3,0,0,0)
lab <- c("SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17","SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37", "SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17", "SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37")
pct <- round(bar/sum(bar)*100)
lab <- paste(lab,"%", sep = "")
lab <- paste(lab, pct)
lab0 <- c("SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17", "SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37", "SN_02", "SN_03", "SN_04", "SN_05", "SN_09", "SN_10", "SN_17", "SN_19", "SN_20", "SN_31", "SN_32", "SN_33", "SN_34", "SN_37")
nlab <- length(lab)
type <- rep("Uniprot:MACKI", each=nlab/2)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
dd <- data.frame(lab0, type, bar, pct)
dd$lab0 <- reorder(dd$lab0,-dd$bar)
ggplot(dd,aes(x=lab0,y=bar,fill=lab0))+
  geom_bar( aes(alpha=factor(bar)) , stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=1) ) +
  scale_alpha_discrete( range=c(0.5,1.0) )+
  geom_text( 
    aes( label=paste0(pct,"%") , group=interaction(lab0,type) ), 
    hjust = -0.5, 
    position = position_dodge(width=1)) +
  coord_flip()+
  expand_limits(y = 20) +
  labs(x = "",y = "total")
```

I advise you also to follow [r-code-formatting-guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml), which would help you to write code in a proper readable way. Good luck!